# xCode 4.5 New file > Sub Class of __add_unsigned?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

When i try to add a new file to my project i am not able to choose a subclass of it.

I do these steps:
Objective-C class > Next > When i open the Subclass of combobox the combobox is filled with the correct classes for like 1 nanosecond.. then it all changes to __add_unsigned..[image]

Anyone knows why it shows like this?